# Using Leaflet.motion plugin on geometry returned by WFS service?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, wfs, leaflet-plugins

I'm back with my Leaflet.motion service because I'd like to link it to an existing WFS service for easier and live updating.

The Javascript plugin for WFS and Leaflet motion are:

```
  <script src="https://iamtekson.github.io/leaflet-geoserver-request/src/L.Geoserver.js"></script>
 <script src="https://mappingforyou.eu/javascript/leaflet.motion.min.js"></script>
```

I have the error: "Uncaught TypeError: wfsLayer.features is undefined"

The code successfully loads the WFS onto the map:

```
var wfsLayer = L.Geoserver.wfs("https://mappingforyou.eu/geoserver/worldmap/ows", {
    layers: "worldmap:debra",
});
wfsLayer.addTo(map);
    

dataCoords = [];

wfsLayer.features[0].geometry.coordinates.forEach(function(coords) {   dataCoords.push([coords[1], coords[0]]); });

            var seqGroup = L.motion.seq([
                    L.motion.polyline(dataCoords, {
                    color: "MediumVioletRed",
                    
                    weight: 10,
                    
                    opacity: 0.8
                    
                    }, {
                        easing: L.Motion.Ease.easeInOutQuad
                    }, {
                        removeOnEnd: false,
                        icon: L.divIcon({html: "<i class='fa fa-male fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i>", iconSize: L.point(27.5, 24)})
                    }).motionDuration(8000)
                ]).addTo(map);


            seqGroup.on("click", function(){
                seqGroup.motionStart();
            });

            seqGroup.on("dblclick", function(e){
                seqGroup.motionToggle();
            });

            setTimeout(function () {
                seqGroup.motionStart();
            }, 1000);
```

But it's not showing the motion

the wfs service is
https://mappingforyou.eu/geoserver/worldmap/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=worldmap%3Adebra&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=text%2Fjavascript

Any help please?

page is at https://mappingforyou.eu/italia/test1.html

Comment: is there any response from the server? if so what is it? what is sent to the server?

Comment: @IanTurton from the console I have Uncaught TypeError: featureLayer.features is undefined

Comment: what about in the network tab? and please use the [edit] button to update your question

Comment: @IanTurton the WFS is found but not showing, I edited the question, It's found at https://mappingforyou.eu/italia/test1.html

Comment: Your are loading WFS layer `featureLayer` async, so `featureLayer.features[0]` is available only after layer is loaded. You are probably referencing it before that.

Comment: @TomazicM thanks but it don't really know how to change that..

Comment: Put your points loading code `featureLayer.features[0].geometry.coordinates.forEach(function(coords) {
  dataCoords.push([coords[1], coords[0]]);
});` at the end of `loadGeoJson` function.

Comment: @TomazicM as the code began to be very difficult, I thought it was better to change the WFS code for a simpler one with another Plugin. I changed my text in consequence. Now I have a different error. It may be easier this time if you can please look at it again..

Comment: What different error? If you have a new/different question, post it as a separate question, otherwise it's not a focused question but a debugging mess.

Comment: @Tomazic well the question remains the same: link WFS to Leaflet.motion.. I began to think my initial WFS code wasn't appropriate because it had a bbox difficulty useless in this case.

Comment: the different error is now "wfsLayer.features is undefined"

Comment: this is quite the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L.Geoserver.wfs` is async method, so any data in `wfsLayer` is accessible only after layer is loaded. `L.Geoserver.wfs` is extension of `L.FeatureGroup` which means it fires `layeradd` event after layer is loaded/added.

Since the above `L.Geoserver.wfs` call returns `MultiLineString`, this has to be checked when converting geometry to array of coordinates.

Taking all this into account, code could look something like this (tested):

```
var dataCoords = [];

function doMotion() {
  var seqGroup = L.motion.seq([
    L.motion.polyline(dataCoords, {
    color: "MediumVioletRed",
    weight: 10,
    opacity: 0.8
    }, {
      easing: L.Motion.Ease.easeInOutQuad
    }, {
      removeOnEnd: false,
      icon: L.divIcon({html: "<i class='fa fa-male fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i>", iconSize: L.point(27.5, 24)})
    }).motionDuration(8000)
  ]).addTo(map);
  seqGroup.on("click", function(){
    seqGroup.motionStart();
  });
  seqGroup.on("dblclick", function(e){
    seqGroup.motionToggle();
  });
  setTimeout(function () {
    seqGroup.motionStart();
  }, 1000);
}
  
var wfsLayer = L.Geoserver.wfs("https://mappingforyou.eu/geoserver/worldmap/ows", {
  layers: "worldmap:debra",
});
wfsLayer.on('layeradd', function(evt) {
  var coords;
  var geometry = evt.layer.feature.geometry;
  if (geometry.type = 'MultiLineString')
    coords = geometry.coordinates[0];
  else if (geometry.type = 'LineString')
    coords = geometry.coordinates;
  else {
    return;
  }
  coords.forEach(function(coords) {
     dataCoords.push([coords[1], coords[0]]);
  });
  doMotion();
});

wfsLayer.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time @TomazicM . It's working . Now I'll try my best to study and understand what has changed between the two versions.It'll be very useful to me. By the way I still havve trouble to understand the word "asynchronous" in this matter..